# Content Security Policy with Chrome Extensions - Getting data via remote URL

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I've made a chrome extension with the following line in the manifest.json, so that I can get data via an ajax request.

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost; object-src 'self'",`

I want to test the extension with my live site, so I changed it to:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://www.example.com; object-src 'self'",`

but now the extension doesn't initialize when I start chrome.

Comment: can you paste the error message

Comment: where would the error messaged be logged if the extension fails to load?

Comment: for content-script : press F12(open developer tool) and reload the page in console section of developer tool you would see the error

Comment: unfortunately the console didn't display any errors relating to the extension not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make cross-origin XHRs, you don't need to care about CSP. What you need to add in the manifest is host permissions for those hosts you need to access. Read https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/xhr.html for more information.

On the other hand, if your extension loads scripts (<script src="..."></script>) from an external web server, you must be aware of CSP. First, the server hosting the scripts must be HTTPS. Then, whilelist it in CSP as described in https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script.

Whitelisting a HTTP origin in 'script-src' is prohibited to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks and other security isuses so that your extension doesn't load.

Comment: Thanks. I had to amend it to `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.example.com; object-src 'self'"`. I just need to find a way to get my site working via https now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added permissions, if not then try this, hope it would work

```
,
 "permissions": [
   "http://www.example.com/*", 
   "tabs"
 ],
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
        "http://www.example.com/*"
    ],
    "js": [
        "js/myScript.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: added the line but it still doesn't load.